# Hadoop Job fails on java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, hadoop, classnotfoundexception

I have searched for solutions to this problem to no avail. I have three scala classes: `MaxTemperatureMapper`, `MaxTemperatureReducer`, and `MaxTemperatureDriver` (See implementation below). Some people in previous threads removed the `job.setJar()` method in the Main class(`MaxTemperatureDriver`) to get the hadoop job running. That did not work for me. I continue to receive the following stacktrace when running either:

1. `hadoop com.koadr.hadoop.MaxTemperatureDriver  micro/sample.txt output`
2. `hadoop jar target/classes/koadr-hadoop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.koadr.hadoop.MaxTemperatureDriver  micro/sample.txt output`:

.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.koadr.hadoop.MaxTemperatureMapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1587)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.koadr.hadoop.MaxTemperatureMapper not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1493)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1585)
... 8 more
```

I am working in an intellij IDE and am using maven for dependencies, compiling, etc. I am running the aforementioned hadoop commands on the command line. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong? Why isn't the Mapper class not being found?

MaxTemperatureMapper :

```
class MaxTemperatureMapper extends Mapper[Object, Text, Text, IntWritable] {

  private def missing( temp : String) : Boolean = {
    temp.equals("+9999")
  }

 override def map(key: Object, value: Text, context:Mapper[Object,Text,Text,IntWritable]#Context ) = {
    val line : String = value.toString
    val year : String = line.substring(15, 19)
    val temp : String = line.substring(87,92)


    if (!missing(temp)) {
        val airTemp : Int = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(87,92))
        context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemp))
    }
  }
}
```

MaxTemperatureReducer:

```
class MaxTemperatureReducer extends Reducer[Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable] {

  override
  def reduce (key: Text, values: java.lang.Iterable[IntWritable], context:Reducer[Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable]#Context) = {
    def maxVal(values : List[IntWritable], cMaxV : Int) : Int = {
      if (values.isEmpty) cMaxV
      else maxVal(values.tail,math.max(cMaxV, values.head.get()))
    }
    context write(new Text(key), new IntWritable(maxVal(values.toList,Integer.MIN_VALUE)) )
  }

}
```

MaxTemperatureDriver:

```
class MaxTemperatureDriver extends Configured with Tool {
  override
  def run(args : Array[String]) : Int = {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.err.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <input> <output>\n", getClass.getSimpleName)
      ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err)
     -1
    }
   val job : Job = Job.getInstance(getConf, "Max Temperature")
   job.setJarByClass(getClass)

   FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args(0)))
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args(1)))

   job.setMapperClass(classOf[MaxTemperatureMapper])
   job.setCombinerClass(classOf[MaxTemperatureReducer])
   job.setReducerClass(classOf[MaxTemperatureReducer])

   job.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[Text])
   job.setOutputValueClass(classOf[IntWritable])

   if (job.waitForCompletion(true))  0 else 1

   }


 }

object MaxTemperatureDriver {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
  val exitCode : Int = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperatureDriver, args)
  System.exit(exitCode)

  }
}
```

Comment: Had you set your hadoop classpath? Run "hadoop classpath" to see what it is, and make sure the .class files are in one of those dirs.

Comment: haddop classpath includes target/classes/, which has nested MaxTemperatureDriver.class,MaxTemperatureDriver$.class,  MaxTemperatureMapper.class, and MaxTemperatureReducer.class

Comment: Can you paste the output of `jar tvf target/classes/koadr-hadoop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` so we can see the classes that are bundled into the jar

Comment: Hey Chris, don't want to paste out the entire thing as it seems to include the scala lib. Tried a grep jar tvf hadoop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep com.koadr.hadoop, which didn't include the class files. Not sure why it would be the case that the files aren't in the jar. I have the surefire plugin in my pom.xml file as well as the scala tools repo.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add any dependencies to both the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `-libjars` upon submitting a job like in the following examples:

Use the following to add all the jar dependencies from (for example) current and `lib` directories:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`echo *.jar`:`echo lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'`
```

Bear in mind that when starting a job through `hadoop jar` you'll need to also pass it the jars of any dependencies through use of `-libjars`. I like to use:

```
hadoop jar <jar> <class> -libjars `echo ./lib/*.jar | sed 's/ /,/g'` [args...]
```

**NOTE:** The `sed` commands require a different delimiter character; the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` is `:` separated and the `-libjars` need to be `,` separated.